# SQL: Counting occurrences based on the value of 2 fields

Tags: sql

I am looking for an efficient way to count occurrences of a combination of 2 field values.

Here is my table:

```
field1   field2
1        a
1        b
1        b
2        a
2        b
```

Field 2 has a predefined set of possible values (let's say "a" and "b").
I need to add columns that count how many rows there are for the current field1 value for each possible value in field 2 (e.g. for field1=1 there is 1 occurrence of field2="a" and 2 occurrences of field2="b")
Output would be something like:

```
field1   field2  field2_a_count  field2_b_count
1        a       1               2
1        b       1               2
1        b       1               2
2        a       1               1
2        b       1               1
```

Sub-queries do the job but are slow. I could not figure our a solution with windowing functions, which are more efficient.

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field1=t.field1 AND field2='a') AS field2_a_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field1=t.field1 AND field2='b') AS field2_b_count,
FROM table t
```

Any way I can improve the efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this calculation using window functions:

```
SELECT field1, field2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) as field2_a_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) as field2_b_count
FROM table t;
```